# How do i know when my android application instance no longer exists?

Tags: android, android-service, background-service

I am making an application for which I want to logout the user whenever he removes the app from recent used apps or the app no longer it exists in the background. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably put your logout code in your `onDestroy()` method of all the activities you are using in your app.

Actually, to be safe, you should save things in onPause() because (at least pre-3.0) your process can be killed by the OS after it calls onPause(). This implies that onStop() and onDestroy() may or may not be called , but then it would make no sense to put your logout code in `onPause()` method.

In any case, there is no guarantee that onDestroy() will ever be called. If the OS decides to kill your process it won't bother calling onDestroy() on any activities.
But if there is any place you should put your logout code it should be `onDestroy()`.

Comment: can't there be any way like writing a service by which i can know the existence of my application

Comment: Well its a very tricky thing to do because when you are removing your application from the running apps list, then no code of that app is guaranteed to execute since the app no more exists.

Comment: ya parag i agree to your point but service always runs untill application stops right.When the user removes the app from running list app and can't i hit the server whenever user removes the app instance